# Does the \bibliography command specify a \section* anywhere?

Tags: sectioning, bibliographies, starred-version

I'm using a class based off the `scrartcl` class. I need to include a bibliography entry in a section, but it displays it as having a `*` for the section title. If I use the command

```
\section*{hello}
```

in the document it displays as

```
*
___
hello
```

and similarly

```
\section{Publications}
\nocite{ref1}
\bibliographystyle{test}
\bibliography{myreflist}
```

displays as

```
PUBLICATIONS
--
*
___
[1] Ref1 etc,
```

I've used the

```
\renewcommand{\refname}{}
```

command to remove the title "References" from the bibliography, but this asterisk is annoying. Does anyone know if the bibliography command uses the `\section*` command anywhere, and how one might change/remove it?

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{tccv}

\section{Publications}
\nocite{ref1}
\bibliographystyle{test}
\bibliography{References}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The command `\thebibliography` issues a `\section*{\refname}`. The first command is automatically called within `\bibliography{...}`

Comment: And I forgot: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thank you, I solved it by redefining \thebibliography in the preamble to not use the \section*{} command.

Comment: `bibliography=totocnumbered` as global option.

Comment: @Ashiataka: What the hell is `tccv` class? Did you not mean `scrartcl`?

Answer (score 5):

This does not solve the deficiencies of the class file, but:

```
\documentclass[bibliography=totocnumbered]{tccv}
\begin{document}
\nocite{companion}
\section{Publications}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\end{document}
```

Use the proper documented interface to get a numbered (i.e. non starred) bibliography.

Or to make it completely obvius:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[bibliography=totocnumbered]{tccv}
\renewcommand{\refname}{Publications}
\begin{document}
\nocite{companion}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\end{document}
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzIsy.png)[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `thebibliography` does issue `\section*` under the [`tccv` document class](http://dev.entidi.com/p/tccv/). In fact, `tccv` redefines `\section` to suit its own needs without taking into account that `\section` could be used in a starred form:

```
% Overrides the \section command to capitalize every
% word for cosmetic purposes and draws a rule under it.
\let\old@section\section
\renewcommand\section[2][]{%
  \old@section[#1]{\ucwords{#2}}%
  \newdimen\raising%
  \raising=\dimexpr-0.7\baselineskip\relax%
  \vskip\raising\hrule height 0.4pt\vskip-\raising}
```

You can correct this in two ways by adding the following to your document preamble:

1. Add dummy starred functionality to `\section`:

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \let\tccvsection\section
   \renewcommand{\section}{\@ifstar\tccvsection\tccvsection}
   \makeatother
   ```
2. Patch `\bib@heading` using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

   ```
   \usepackage{etoolbox}
   \makeatletter
   % \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
   \patchcmd{\bib@heading}{\section*}{\section}{}{}
   \makeatother
   ```

Here's a minimal example using the former option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{tccv}
\makeatletter
\let\tccvsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{\@ifstar\tccvsection\tccvsection}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Publications}

\begin{thebibliography}{x}
  \bibitem{abc} Some bibliography item
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Now you should be able to change the bibliography heading to suit your needs using an appropriate

```
\renewcommnd{\refname}{<your new bibliography heading>}
```

if you wish.

Comment: The two headings are clearly wrong.

Comment: @egreg: Clearly. The OP shows the use of what sections should look like `\section{Publications}` and then how it's set in the bibliography. I kept the input as-is.

Comment: Note that the OP says to have tried doing `\renewcommand{\refname}{}` to suppress the heading.

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly an error in the `tccv` class redefining `\section` so that it doesn't honor a `*` after it.

You solve the issue by defining `\bib@heading` to do nothing.

```
\documentclass{tccv}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\bib@heading}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Publications}
\nocite{Knuth:ct-a}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{texbook1}

\end{document}
```

[image]