# Change font in tccv

Tags: fonts

I want to change the font globally for all sections and headings to the default font (Computer Modern). What do I need to change in this tccv template:

https://de.overleaf.com/latex/templates/my-two-column-cv/qmdfhjwnzqqy

```
NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
ProvidesClass{tccv}
             [2015/04/16 v1.2.2
Two Column Curriculum Vitae]

LoadClassWithOptions{scrartcl}

setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
RequirePackage[hmargin=1.25cm,vmargin=1.25cm,twocolumn,columnsep=1.25cm]{geometry}
RequirePackage{bookman,etoolbox,needspace,pifont,tabularx,xcolor}
RequirePackage{hyperref}

 Capitalize words of at least a minimum length (default to 3 chars).
 The text is capitalized before being expanded.

 This macro uses Lua to do the job but fails gracefully (that is,
 return the text as is) if \directlua is not available.

     \ucwords
         [optional: miminum length]{text}
newcommand\ucwords[2][3]{%
   % Fails gracefully if not in LuaLaTeX
   \providecommand\directlua[1]{#2}%
   \directlua{%
    local minlen = tonumber("#1")
    local src = "\luaescapestring{\unexpanded{#2}}"
    local dst = {}
    % Put a % inside \directlua is tricky as hell. Use char(37)
    % instead: still no plans for supporting non-ASCII platforms.
    for w in src:gmatch(string.char(37) .. "S+") do
        if w:len() >= minlen then
        table.insert(dst, w:sub(1,1):upper() .. w:sub(2))
        else
        table.insert(dst, w)
        end
    end
    tex.print(dst)}}

pagestyle{empty}
setlength\parindent{0pt}
color[HTML]{303030} % Default foreground color
definecolor{link}{HTML}{506060} % Hyperlinks
hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=link,linkcolor=link}
setkomafont{disposition}{\color[HTML]{801010}}
setkomafont{section}{\scshape\Large\mdseries}

 In tccv \part must contain the subject of the curriculum vitae.
 The command will start a new page and output in onecolumn the
 subject (first and last name) with the text from the optional
 argument underneath it
renewcommand\part[2][Curriculum Vitae]{%
   \twocolumn[%
   \begin{center}
    \vskip-\lastskip%
    {\usekomafont{part} #2} \medskip\\
    {\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont\Huge {#1}}
    \bigskip
   \end{center}]}

 Overrides the \section command to capitalize every
 word for cosmetic purposes and draws a rule under it.
let\old@section\section
renewcommand\section[2][]{%
   \old@section[#1]{\ucwords{#2}}%
   \newdimen\raising%
   \raising=\dimexpr-0.7\baselineskip\relax%
   \vskip\raising\hrule height 0.4pt\vskip-\raising}

 Allow conditionals based on the job name. This can usually be set
 from a command-line argument: check fausto.en.tex for an example.

     \ifjob
         {jobname}
         {content if matches}
         {content if does not match}
newcommand\ifjob[3]{%
   \edef\JOBNAME{\jobname}%
   \edef\PIVOT{\detokenize{#1}}%
   \ifdefstrequal{\JOBNAME}{\PIVOT}{#2}{#3}%


 Renders a personal data box:

     \personal
         [url without scheme, i.e. no http:// prefix]
         {address}
         {phone number}
         {email}
newcommand\personal[4][]{%
   \newcommand\SYMBOL[1]{\raisebox{-2pt}{\Large\ding{##1}}}%
   \needspace{0.5\textheight}%
   \newdimen\boxwidth%
   \boxwidth=\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax%
   \colorbox[HTML]{F5DD9D}{%
   \begin{tabularx}{\boxwidth}{c|X}
   \SYMBOL{45} & {#2}\smallskip\\
   \SYMBOL{37} & {#3}\smallskip\\
   \SYMBOL{41} & \href{mailto:#4}{#4}
   \ifstrempty{#1}{}{\smallskip\\ \SYMBOL{218} & \href{http://#1}{#1}}
   \end{tabularx}}}

 Every \item can be followed by one or more paragraphs
 of description:

     \item
         {date range}
         {company}
         {role}
     One or more paragraphs describing what achieved during this application.
newenvironment{eventlist}{%
   \newcommand*\inskip{}
   \renewcommand\item[3]{%
    \inskip%
    {\raggedleft\textsc{##1}\\[1pt]}
    \ifstrempty{##2}{}{##2\\[2pt]}
    {\Large\textit{##3}}
    \medskip
    \renewcommand\inskip{\bigskip}}}
   {\bigskip}

 Use only \item inside this environment, no other macros
 are allowed:

     \item
         [what has been achieved]
         {years}
         {subject}
         {notes}
newenvironment{yearlist}{%
   \renewcommand\item[4][]{%
    \textsc{##2} & \textbf{##3} \\
    \ifstrempty{##1}{}{& \textsc{##1} \\}
    & \textit{##4}\medskip\\}
   \tabularx{\linewidth}{rX}}
   {\endtabularx}


 Use only \item inside this environment: no other macros
 are allowed:

     \item
         {fact}
         {description}
newenvironment{factlist}{%
   \newdimen\unbaseline
   \unbaseline=\dimexpr-\baselinestretch\baselineskip\relax
   \renewcommand\item[2]{%
    \textsc{##1} & {\raggedright ##2\medskip\\}\\[\unbaseline]}
   \tabularx{\linewidth}{rX}}
   {\endtabularx}

 Avoid dealing with starred sections
 See the following question for further details:
 http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223607/does-the-bibliography-command-specify-a-section-anywhere
KOMAoption{bibliography}{totocnumbered}

AtEndPreamble{%
    \@ifpackageloaded{biblatex}{%
        \defbibheading{bibliography}[\refname]{%
            \section{#1}%
        }%
    }{}%

%
% End of file `tccv.cls'.
```

Comment: You originally wrote, “I want to change the font globally for all sections and headings,” but then you commented, “I want to use computer modern for every single line: headings and body text.” Which is it?

Comment: If you can’t change the document class, change the main font to a clone of Computer Modern in your `.tex` file with `\usepackage{lmodern}`.  If you can edit the class file, take out `bookman` and any other package you don’t actually use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MWE does not seem to have been copied over correctly, but I think I can figure out what you meant.  You’re setting your font with the obsolescent `bookman` package right now.  You’ll want to select a different font with the `\setkomafont{disposition}{\color[HTML]{801010}}` command.

One thing I’m not clear on is whether you genuinely want to use Computer Modern for headings and Bookman for the body text.  I wonder if you didn’t really mean, how do you get headings to use the body font?  The command for that is

```
\setkomafont{disposition}{\color[HTML]{801010}\rmfamily}
```

One option you have, since you’re not sending your source to a publisher who still requires you to use 8-bit fonts in 2021, is to upgrade to LuaLaTeX.  This lets you use modern desktop fonts.  I personally recommend doing this when you can and using legacy fonts when you have to.  In this case, you want to remove the `bookman` package and add:

```
\usepackage{xcolor} % Include this only once, before fontspec.
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola} % Or your font of choice

% Because LuaTeX does not properly load NewComputerModernBook.fontspec:
\newfontfamily\newcm{NewComputerModern}[
    Extension = .otf ,
    UprightFont = NewCM10-Book,
    ItalicFont = NewCM10-BookItalic,
    BoldFont = NewCM10-Bold,
    BoldItalicFont = NewCM10-BoldItalic,
    SlantedFont = NewCM10-Book,
    BoldSlantedFont = NewCM10-Bold,
    SmallCapsFeatures = {Numbers=OldStyle},
    Scale = MatchUppercase,
    Ligatures = Common]

\setkomafont{disposition}{\color[HTML]{801010}\newcm}
```

This will set the font of all your headers to a slightly less-thin form of Computer Modern.  You can tweak this to use the Regular weight, or replace `\newcm` with `\rmfamily` to use a clone of Bookman for both headers and body text.

A much shorter definition of `\newcm`, which suffices for headings, would be:

```
\newfontface\newcm{NewCM10-Book.otf}
```

If you want to stick with Computer Modern in PDFTeX, replace `bookman` with `tgschola` or `kerkis`, add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, and change the `\setkomafont` command to:

```
\setkomafont{disposition}{\color[HTML]{801010}\fontfamily(cmr)}
```

Comment: I want to use computer modern for every single line: headings and body text. I tried `\setkomafont{disposition}{\color[HTML]{801010}\rmfamily}` and ´\setkomafont{disposition}{\color[HTML]{801010}\fontfamily(cmr)}´. But I didn't find where to set `tgschola` instead of `bookman`. So it didn't work. I deleted the line `\setkomafont{disposition}{\color[HTML]{801010}}` and then it worked.

Comment: Sorry, deleting the line `\setkomafont{disposition}{\color[HTML]{801010}}` only worked for the headings.

Comment: I finally managed to change the font for the whole document to the ssfamily by including `\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}` in the preamble.

Comment: @yPennylane I usually advise people who have problems because they’re using some big template with too many packages to comment out **all** the packages. Add them back, one by one, until you find out which ones you actually need.

Comment: @yPennylane In this case, you load `bookman` with a `\RequirePackage` command. So, you can take that out and replace it with `\RequirePackage{tgschola}` would solve a different problem than the one you had.

Comment: @yPennylane Your **actual** problem is that you wrote, “I want to change the font globally for all sections and headings,” so I answered that question. But what you actually wanted was something completely different. The default font is Computer Modern Roman. To keep it, remove `bookman` and any other package that changes the main font. You can also add `\usepackage{lmodern}` to load a clone.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the preamble or `.cls` file, and compile with `lualatex`.

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond} % Or whatever
```