# 1. Why can't hebrew be passed as an option to babel? 2. Is \babelprovide's import option necessary? 3. Why is \babelprovide's main option necessary?

Tags: luatex, babel, hebrew, right-to-left

The following questions were spurred by mere curiosity, not by any practical problem.

---

**Part 1**

The following LaTeX code compiles successfully with `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

Likewise, the following LaTeX code compiles successfully with `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[main,import]{hebrew}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

However, if you replace `french` by `hebrew`, or `bidi=basic,hebrew` in the first example, compilation fails with the following error message:

```
To avoid this error message,
run TeX--XeT or e-TeX engine instead of regular TeX.

! Right-to-Left Support Error: use TeX--XeT or e-TeX engine.
l.63      engine}
               %
? 
! Emergency stop.
l.63 
   
End of file on the terminal!
```

1. Why isn't it possible to pass `babel` the `hebrew` option directly, possibly alongside `bidi=basic`?

---

**Part 2**

The examples I've been recommended to follow for setting up a Hebrew document with `babel`+`luatex` contain the line `\babelprovide[main,import]{hebrew}` in their preamble, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[main,import]{hebrew}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

2. Is the `import` option necessary? If it is dropped, does it make any difference?
3. I did notice that the `main` option is necessary: without it the document's default directionality is left to right. But why is this the case if only `hebrew` was specified as a language, which implies that this is a monolingual Hebrew document, and therefore its directionality should be right to left?

Comment: the old hebrew.ldf loaded when you use it as option is not compatible with lualatex.

Comment: See https://latex3.github.io/babel/guides/which-method-for-which-language.html

Comment: @JavierBezos Thank you. This is helpful. Incidentally, the page you linked to suggests the font `NewCM` for Hebrew. The page states that this font is included in TeXLive. However, I get a compilation error when I try to load this font with `\babelfont`.

Comment: `...texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/newcomputermodern/...`  has font files with Hebrew in them, including presentation forms, e.g., `NewCM10-Regular.otf`'. [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597547/change-font-in-tccv/601672#601672) maybe related.

Comment: @Cicada Thanks. This is helpful. Incidentally, many fonts, including `NewCM10`, make the mistake of italicizing Hebrew text wrongly: they make the letters slant in the opposite direction of the text flow. I find this very unfortunate. One font that gets it correctly is `HadasimCLM` (TrueType).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Javier Bezos in [his comment to my original post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/665978/1-why-cant-hebrew-be-passed-as-an-option-to-babel-2-is-babelprovides-impor#comment1655999_665978), the Hebrew language can be specified as an option to the `babel` package, rather than as an argument to the `\babeprovide` command, and the `\babelprovide` command can be eliminated, together with its `main` and `import` options, at the price of passing one more option to the `babel` package, namely `provide=*`. Putting all this together, instead of

```
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[main,import]{hebrew}
```

one can write, equivalently,

```
\usepackage[bidi=basic,hebrew,provide=*]{babel}
```

---

N.B. I think it would be nice if there were another `babel` option, say `heb`, or `Hebrew` (with a capital first letter), that would abbreviate the three options shown above, so the `hebrew` language could be loaded with the necessary/recommended settings by writing, say, `\usepackage[heb]{babel}`, similarly to the way European languages, like French, are loaded.

Comment: Sure. It could be added in the future, with some kind of rule (eg, use the `ldf` if exists, the `ini` file otherwise), but it can’t be done hastily.