# Why can't Hebrew be passed as an option to the babel package when the document class is beamer (beamer-rl)?

Tags: beamer, babel, hebrew, right-to-left, options

A couple weeks ago [I asked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/665978/21685) whether it was possible to specify Hebrew as an option to the `babel` package, rather than specifying it with the `\babelprovide` command. A comment from Javier Bezos indicated that it was in fact possible to specify Hebrew as a package option, as described in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/666039/21685).

However, it appears that while this solution works for the `article` document class, it fails for `beamer` (or, more accurately, for `beamer-rl`, which, to my understanding, is a wrapper class for `beamer` that should be used when the presentation's language has right-to-left text flow, like Hebrew).

As an example, consider the following LaTeX code, saved in the file `~/Test.tex`.

```
\documentclass{beamer-rl}
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}

\babelprovide[import,main]{hebrew}
\babelfont{rm}{FreeSerif}
\babelfont{sf}{FreeSans}
\babelfont{tt}{FreeMono} 
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Hello, world!
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

When the following commands are executed in the Terminal:

```
> cd ~
> lualatex Test
```

a file `~/Test.pdf` is generated, which, when opened in a PDF viewer, displays as follows.

[image: A simple Hebrew beamer presentation]

Bear in mind that Hebrew is a right-to-left language, and so the text's right-justification and right-to-left text flow are expected, and correct, and do not indicate a problem.

If now the two lines

```
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import,main]{hebrew}
```

are replaced by

```
\usepackage[bidi=basic,hebrew,provide=*]{babel}
```

and the code is recompiled, the compilation fails, and the following error message appears in `~/Test.log`.

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package babel.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.6 \babelfont
            {rm}{FreeSerif}
? 
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.6 \babelfont
            {rm}{FreeSerif}
The package babel has already been loaded with options:
  [nil,bidi=basic]
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [bidi=basic,hebrew,provide=*]
Adding the global options:
  nil,bidi=basic,bidi=basic,hebrew,provide=*
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
```

---

**Question**

Why is it not possible to pass Hebrew as an option to the `babel` package when the document class is `beamer`, when it is possible to do so when the document class is `article`? Is there an easy fix for this issue?

---

**Motivations**

There are at least two motivations for fixing the behavior reported above. One of these motivations is satified by the solution suggested by Salim Bou in [a comment below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/668103/why-cant-hebrew-be-passed-as-an-option-to-the-babel-package-when-the-document-c#comment1660854_668103). The other motivation requires a different solution.

**Motivation 1**

One motivation for a fix is so that it would be possible to use the same Latex-programming idiom with Hebrew as with other languages, not only w.r.t. `beamer`, but w.r.t. other packages as well.

Take, for example, the `translator` package which is loaded automatically by `beamer` and normally picks up the languages passed to `beamer` as class options.

With German it is possible to add custom translations as follows.

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{Sayings-German.dict}
\deftranslation{saying}{What doesn't kill me, makes me stronger.}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[german]{beamer}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\babelfont{rm}{FreeSerif}
\babelfont{sf}{FreeSans}
\babelfont{tt}{FreeMono}

\usedictionary{Sayings}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\translate{saying}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Note that the `german` class option is mandatory for the translation to be carried out.

However, with Hebrew the same functionality requires the addition of the command `\uselanguage{hebrew}` in the preamble, and, if it is desired to use the capitalized version `Hebrew`, as is customary with `translator`, whose commands normally accept capitalized language names, the additional command `\languagealias{hebrew}{Hebrew}` needs to be added, like so.

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{Sayings-Hebrew.dict}
\deftranslation{saying}{If I won't fend for myself, who will fend for me?}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{beamer-rl}
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}

\babelprovide[import,main]{hebrew}
\babelfont{rm}{FreeSerif}
\babelfont{sf}{FreeSans}
\babelfont{tt}{FreeMono}

\usedictionary{Sayings}

% The following two commands are not necessary with German,
% because German can be passed to beamer as a class option.
\languagealias{hebrew}{Hebrew}
\uselanguage{Hebrew}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\translate{saying}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This problem can be solved by [Salim Bou's suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/668103/why-cant-hebrew-be-passed-as-an-option-to-the-babel-package-when-the-document-c#comment1660854_668103), namely passing the option list `[babel={hebrew,provide=*},hebrew]` to the `beaber-rl` document class. Using this trick, the last piece of code can be rewritten in a manner similar to the code for the German presentation given above.

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{Sayings-Hebrew.dict}
\deftranslation{saying}{If I won't fend for myself, who will fend for me?}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[babel={hebrew,provide=*},hebrew]{beamer-rl}

\babelfont{rm}{FreeSerif}
\babelfont{sf}{FreeSans}
\babelfont{tt}{FreeMono}

\usedictionary{Sayings}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\translate{saying}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This code compiles successfully, and the resulting PDF file looks as desired:

[image: A trick to enable passing beamer-rl hebrew as a class option]

**Motivation 2**

Another motivation for a fix, and one that cannot be put to rest by Salim Bou's suggestion, is to have a single common preamble file for both articles and presentations.

I currently have a file called `Preamble.tex`, where I collect all the customizations that are applicable across-the-board to all the documents of class `article` that I write. The preamble of every such document consists simply of inputing this common file, thus:

```
\documentclass{article}
\input{Preamble.tex}
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

One of the customizations in `Preamble.tex` sets up Hebrew as the main language via `babel`:

```
\usepackage[bidi=basic,hebrew,provide=*]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{FreeSerif}
\babelfont{sf}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{FreeSans}
\babelfont{tt}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{FreeMono}
```

I'd like to be able to input `Preamble.tex` to all my `beamer` presentations as well. Unfortunately, Salim Bou's solution fails for this scenario, and I cannot see how to modify his solution to accommodate this scenario.

It won't do to have one preamble file for `article`s, and one for `beamer`s, because this would introduce a lot of duplicate code whose maintenance would be tedious and error-prone, and undermine to an extent the whole point of having a centralized preamble file.

Comment: The class already loads babel: `\RequirePackage[nil,bidi=basic]{babel}`.

Comment: You can use `\documentclass[babel={hebrew,provide=*}]{beamer-rl}`, this pass options to babel

Comment: You don't need  `\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}` the class calls `babel` implicitly

Comment: @SalimBou Thank you. This is a good answer. With `[babel={hebrew,provide=*},hebrew]` I can get rid of the extra two `translator` commands in my last example. If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it. Just please note that in `[babel={hebrew,provide=*}]` `hebrew` is not being passed as a class option to the `beamer` class.

Comment: "It won't do to have one preamble file for articles, and one for beamers, " You can have code for different classes in one file, search for `\IfClassLoadedTF` or `\@ifclassloaded`

Comment: (using a typical article preamble for beamer is almost never a good idea. There are many packages which interfere with beamer's mechanisms and even more which are not necessary in beamer. Instead of using a standard preamble, it is much less risky to only use the packages actually necessary for a given project.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution is based on Salim Dou's suggestions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/668103/why-cant-hebrew-be-passed-as-an-option-to-the-babel-package-when-the-document-c?noredirect=1#comment1660854_668103) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/668103/why-cant-hebrew-be-passed-as-an-option-to-the-babel-package-when-the-document-c/668124?noredirect=1#comment1660940_668124), as well as on [samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz
's suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/668103/why-cant-hebrew-be-passed-as-an-option-to-the-babel-package-when-the-document-c?noredirect=1#comment1660929_668103). Note that [according to Sam Carter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/668103/why-cant-hebrew-be-passed-as-an-option-to-the-babel-package-when-the-document-c?noredirect=1#comment1660932_668103) it's not a good idea to have a single common preamble file for both `article`s and `beamer`s.

---

```
% Sayings-Hebrew.dict
\deftranslation{saying}{If I won't fend for myself, who will fend for me?}
```

---

```
% Preamble.tex
\IfClassLoadedTF{beamer-rl}
{
   % If the current class is 'beamer-rl',
   % babel's language options should be specified
   % as class options as follows:
   % \documentclass[babel={provide=*},hebrew]{beamer-rl}

   % Furthermore, beamer-rl loads the
   % 'translator' class automatically,
   % and will pass it the 'hebrew' class
   % option if it is specified as shown above.
}
{
   % Actions to take if the current class is not 'beamer'.
   \usepackage[bidi=basic,hebrew,provide=*]{babel}
   \usepackage[hebrew]{translator}
}

\babelfont{rm}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{FreeSerif}
\babelfont{sf}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{FreeSans}
\babelfont{tt}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{FreeMono}

\usedictionary{Sayings}
\uselanguage{Hebrew}
```

---

```
% Article.tex
\documentclass{article}
\input{Preamble}
\begin{document}
\translate{saying}
\end{document}
```

[image: An article]

---

```
% Presentation.tex
\documentclass[babel={provide=*},hebrew]{beamer-rl}
\input{Preamble}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\translate{saying}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: A beamer presentation]

Comment: You can just use without typing hebrew twice `\documentclass[babel={provide=*},hebrew]{beamer-rl}`

Comment: @SalimBou Thanks. Very nice! I've changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: I ended up finding a sweet spot between Sam Carter's admonition not to share a preamble between `article`s and `beamer`s and my desire to avoid duplicating code as much as possible. Here's what I've done.

Comment: I've split my `Preamble.tex` file in three: `Preamble.tex`, `Preamble4Article.tex`, and `Preamble4BeamerRL.tex`. All my documents whose document class is `article` input `Preamble4Article.tex` in their preamble, all my documents whose document class is`beamer-rl` input `Preamble4BeamerRL.tex` in their preamble, and both `Preamble4Article.tex` and `Preamble4BeamerRL.tex` input `Preamble.tex`, where I collected all the common settings that can safely be shared between `article`s and `beamer-rl`s.